# Check whether Wireshark file contain bad checksum packets

Tags: wireshark

I am looking for command via command line that tell me whether Wireshark file contain bad checksum packets, not using the GUI but using the command line (maybe via Tshark ?)

i have seen this command here in this forum but cannot find it now.

Answer (score 3):

You can filter packets that has specific field:value with `tshark`. For TCP packets there is `tcp.checksum_bad` field. There can be another field for other protocols. Also fot TCP dissector there is option that enable/disable checksum validation `tcp.check_checksum`.
So to find packet with bad checksum with tshark:

```
tshark -o 'tcp.check_checksum:True' -Y 'tcp.checksum_bad==True' -r input.pcap
```

Also you can try `expert.message=="Bad checksum"` filter.

Comment: Hi, I understand this is a very old answer. But, I was trying it now and I get this error: `Neither "tcp.checksum_bad" nor "True" are field or protocol names`. As I understand it, it's an issue with the display filter (`-Y`), but I have no idea how to fix it. Could you suggest some solution?

Comment: Hi, @GaurangTandon, it loolks like after 2.0.16 version only `tcp.checksum_bad.expert` available. Try to use `-Y 'tcp.checksum_bad.expert'`.

Comment: Thank you! It does work perfectly! May I ask you how you found this particular field. I did `tshark -G protocols | grep checksum` but couldn't find relevant fields (not sure if this is the right method)

Comment: I checked in Wireshark, it has autocompletion. And checked this https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/t/tcp.html for versions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:
`_ws.expert.group == "Checksum"` as the filter, which checks for bad checksum errors.

```
tshark -r input.pcap -Y '_ws.expert.group == "Checksum"'
```